# Проверка регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно построить регулярное выражение для проверки номера телефона (вроде как написал) и внести дополнения в функцию `CheckData()`. Тоесть по нажатию кнопки должно появится уведомление уведомление что номер телефона введен не по шаблону. Вот мои наработки, дальше застрял. Буду рад совету. Заранее спасибо!

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckData()
{
  var ans;
  ans = confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите отправить введенные данные ?");
  if (ans) submit();
  alert("...");
  return false;
  }
 
function isValidPhone(Phone) { 
   return /^\+?\d{1}(?:\(?\d{3}\)?|\d{3})\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$/.test(Phone); 
} 
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
</head>
  <body> 
    <center>
      <form action="z1_1.html" onsubmit="CheckData();return false;">
<center> <b> Для регистрации необходимо указать ваши персональные данные</b></center>
        <table>
<TR><TD>*Имя:</TD> <TD> <input type ="text" name ="Name" size ="15" onChange="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"><br> </TR>
<TR><TD>Организация(компания)</TD><TD> <input TYPE="text" name ="Company" size="15"><br></TD> </TR>
<TR><TD>Телефон</TD><TD> <input type ="text" name ="Phone" size="15"> <br></TD> </TR>
<TR><TD>*Адрес эл.почты</TD><TD> <input type ="text" name ="email" size="15" onChange="this.value=CheckAge(this.value)"
  onFocus="this.select()"> </TD></TR><br>

  <TD><input type="submit" size="15" value="Отправить">
  <input type="reset"></TD>
  <br>
  <TD><left>* Поля обязательные для заполнения</left></TD>

        </table>
      </center>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function CheckData()
{
  var ans;
  ans = confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите отправить введенные данные ?");
  if (ans) submit();
var x=document.forms["z1_1.html"]["Phone"].value;
if (x==null || x=="/^\+?\d{1}(?:\(?\d{3}\)?|\d{3})\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$/")
  {
  alert("Неверный номер телефона");
  return false;
  }
}`  Вот что я смог придумать, но это не работает...

Comment: А почему бы просто не использовать `pattern="regex"` в элементе input? Регулярное выражение работает, как надо?

Comment: Выражение правильное. Я вот просто не понимаю как в уведомлении сделать предупреждение на основе регулярного выражения, что ввод некорректен. Учусь только, многих элементарных вещей не знаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного другая регулярка. Повзволяет использовать коды `+7` и прочие.

```js
const form = document.forms[0];
const input = document.querySelector('#phone');
const rx = /^(\+{0,})(\d{0,})([(]{1}\d{1,3}[)]{0,}){0,}(\s?\d+|\+\d{2,3}\s{1}\d+|\d+){1}[\s|-]?\d+([\s|-]?\d+){1,2}(\s){0,}$/im;
const rx2 = /[^0-9+]/g;
const rx3 = /^(\+\d{1,3})?\d{10,}$/;

function testPhone(phone) {
  return rx.test(phone) && rx3.test(phone.replace(rx2,''));
}

form.addEventListener('input',()=>{
  input.className = '';
  input.classList.add( 
    testPhone(input.value) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
  );
});
```

```css
#phone.valid { border: 1px solid #0f0; background: #cfc; }
#phone.invalid { border: 1px solid #f00; background: #fcc; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="phone">Введите телефон</label>
  <input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+99(333)333-3333"/>
</form>
```

Валидные форматы:

```
(123) 456-7890
(123)456-7890
123-456-7890
1234567890
+31636363634
+3(123) 123-12-12
+3(123)123-12-12
+3(123)1231212
+3(123) 12312123
+3(123) 123 12 12
075-63546725
+7910 120 54 54
910 120 54 54
8 999 999 99 99
```

[Инсточник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099946/14255891)

Comment: Немного добавил кода. Теперь работает более стабильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести предупреждение о правильности регулярного выражения можно через alert вывести следующее
Допустим есть регулярка regEx
И можно сделать так

```
alert(regEx.test(text));
```

text это у нас текст, которые проходит проверку через регулярку, а regEx - сама регулярка
Чтобы было понятнее, напишу блок кода, который недавно использовал

```
var text = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    var regEx = /^([0-9]{1,}[\.,][0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{1,})|(-[0-9]{1,}[\.,][0-9]{1,}|-[0-9]{1,})$/;
    alert(regEx.test(text));
```

Надеюсь поможет)

Comment: Забыл еще сообщить что функция test возвращает boolean